# how i can protect folder in my site by php htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

hello all i`m php developer and i try to use new method in my work i was divide all modules and put it in specific folder .my question how i can protect folder

ex:

```
www.test.com/cms/users/add.php
```

i want if some one try write in url

```
www.test.com/cms/users/
```

redirect too

```
www.test.com/cms/login.php
```

how i can please

Comment: do you have any htaccess? can you paste it?

Comment: btw, this is not a PHP question

Comment: no i dont have yet but i think the way to protect folder is by htaccess isnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this example in all my websites. On the line that is commented, you can see that I'm denying direct access to those folders (application, modules, system), just have to change for your own.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: thx thxxxxxx sir for help i will try when back to home and test it...last help could u tell me nice toturial to understand htaccess ^^

Comment: mmmm this code is protected folder to show but thats not i need i need if some body write www.test.com/folder/hola.php its will open but if try to write ww.test.com/folder/ to hack and show all files in that folder redirect him to www.test.com pleas tell me how

Comment: for that you need to use htaccess as well, check this : http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php

Comment: u dont have already code? cuz i`m beginner and dont understand or learn htaccess yet